Generate and show messages several times in WordPress
I have a WordPress website and I want to generate and show different messages several times for users.
This is my code
function fake_buy_messages(){
    show_fake_buy_messages();
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'fake_buy_messages');

function generate_fake_message(){
    $names = array("John", "Emma", "Michael", "Sophia", "William");
    $products = array("Product A", "Product B", "Product C");
    $name = $names[array_rand($names)];
    $product = $products[array_rand($products)];
    return "$name bought $product";
}

// Function to display the fake buy messages using jQuery
function show_fake_buy_messages() {
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        function showMessage() {
            var message ="<?php echo generate_fake_message() ?>";
            var messageElement = $('<div class="fake-message"></div>').text(message);
            messageElement.css({
                'position': 'fixed',
                'bottom': '20px',
                'left': '20px',
                'background': '#f0f0f0',
                'padding': '10px',
                'border-radius': '5px'
            });
            $('body').append(messageElement);
            setTimeout(function() {
                messageElement.fadeOut(1000, function() {
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            }, 3000); // Hide message after 3 seconds
        }

        // Call showMessage function repeatedly
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            setTimeout(showMessage, i * 10000); // Show messages every 10 seconds
        }    
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
?>

But this code shows the same messages 5 times - for example "Emma bought Product C" but I need to show 5 different random generated messages.

PHP executes on the server side, so var message ="<?php echo generate_fake_message() ?>"; will only output a random value one time. If such fundamentals are not clear to you yet, then you should go and have a read of What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming? first of all.

@maxteprov7, You should use setInterval. Your code is correct, I modified a few things. Check my codes below:
function fake_buy_messages() {
    ?>
    <div id="fake-buy-messages-container"></div>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            function generate_fake_message() {
                var names = ["John", "Emma", "Michael", "Sophia", "William"];
                var products = ["Product A", "Product B", "Product C"];
                var name = names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)];
                var product = products[Math.floor(Math.random() * products.length)];
                
                return name + " bought " + product;
            }

        function showMessage(message) {
            var messageElement = $('<div class="fake-message"></div>').text(message);
            messageElement.css({
                'position': 'fixed',
                'bottom': '20px',
                'left': '20px',
                'background': '#f0f0f0',
                'padding': '10px',
                'border-radius': '5px'
            });
            $('#fake-buy-messages-container').append(messageElement);
            setTimeout(function() {
                messageElement.fadeOut(1000, function() {
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            }, 3000); // Hide message after 3 seconds
        }

        // Display messages periodically
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            var message = generate_fake_message();
            showMessage(message);
        }, 10000);

        var messagesCount = 5;
        var messagesDisplayed = 0;
        var limitInterval = setInterval(function() {
            messagesDisplayed++;
            if (messagesDisplayed >= messagesCount) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                clearInterval(limitInterval);
            }
        }, 10000);

    });
</script>
<?php
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'fake_buy_messages');

